# createRoot(...): Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: reactjs, frontend, create-react-app, react-dom, codesandbox

This error keeps occuring . I use codesandbox to create the React applications. Currently I was hulding a Food Order app using React. And somehow this error keeps popping up . I have imported react and react-dom everywhere. The error keeps saying about some rendering gone wrong. Attached are some images and a snippet of code I am sharing , which is showing error in the index.js file.

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementsByClassName('root'));
root.render(<App />);
```

Comment: Looks like there is no elemement with specified class, most probably you need `getElementById` instead of `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: Hey! Thanks, but I tried that as well, same result

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: Could you also share you `index.html` file (in `public` folder)?